# How to add sprites to a PyGame Group

Tags: python, pygame

I've been at this a while, and essentially this is all the relevant code;

```
hero=pygame.sprite.Group()
snowballs=pygame.sprite.Group()

class main_character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,*groups):
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,*groups)
       self.image=direction
       self.rect=self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
       self.add(hero)


class my_snowball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,*groups):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self,*groups)
        self.image=snowball
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.add(snowballs)

print(hero)
print(snowballs)
```

where direction is the character image and snowball is the snowball image.

The print(hero) and print(snowballs) say that there aren't any sprites in those groups, and I was wondering why. The logic seems to be there, as I am adding the sprites with the rect attribute to the group.

I havn't found a tutorial which fixes this, thanks

Comment: Are you creating an instance of main_character and my_snowball somewhere? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: What does that mean?:(

Comment: \_\_init__ is called whenever you instantiate the class. It basically works like this: instance = Class(). Parameters are passed to the initializer. For example, to create a snowball at (100,100), you could write this: snowball = my_snowball([100,100]). Python will call the initializer for you, and add the sprite to the group.

Comment: Ok thanks, so that line of code would add my_snowball([100,100]) to the group "snowball"?

Comment: It would add it to the "snowballs" group, because that's what \_\_init__ does. You may want to read a bit about classes and instance creating in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do `snowballs.add(self)` and same with the hero.
`pygame.sprite.Group.add(Sprite)`. Or, maybe you could say `global snowballs`
and
`global hero`

Comment: Read the docs. pygame.sprite.Sprite.add(*groups). The Sprite will be added to the Groups it is not already a member of.

Comment: I know it works, but he already had self.add(hero) and self.add(snowballs) in his code. Showing another way to add sprites to groups doesn't solve his problem.